# React native: setState did not update immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-state

I'm trying to make a TicTacToe game for an android app. The TicTacToe's game mode that I'm intended to make is Human-vs-Computer. But the problem is the program did not update the switching-procedure (setState) in my switchPlayer function as the Previous player and Current player is the same after doing the setState. The expected output from switchPlayer function: Previous player: 1, Current player: -1 but the actual output: Previous player: 1, Current player: 1.

I've also tried to use the callback method as suggested/recommended from other Stackoverflow question, but still not working. Am I doing it right? Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Codes are as below:

```
switchPlayer = (newPlayer) => {
   console.log("Previous player: "+this.state.currentPlayer);
   this.setState(

   {currentPlayer: newPlayer},
   function () {console.log("Current player: "+this.state.currentPlayer); }

   );
};

onTilePress = (row, col, ValidMove) => {

   if (ValidMove == 1) {  //If move is valid

       //Dont allow tiles to change
       var value = this.state.gameState[row][col];
       if (value !== 0) { return;}

       //Identify and grab current player
       var PlayerNow = this.state.currentPlayer;   

       console.log(row, col, PlayerNow);
       //Set the correct tile...
       var arr = this.state.gameState.slice();
       arr[row][col] = PlayerNow;
       this.setState({gameState: arr});

       //Switch to other player
       if (PlayerNow == 1) { //if player 1, then change to bot
           this.switchPlayer(-1);
       }            
       else if (PlayerNow == -1) {
           this.switchPlayer(1);
       }

       console.log("New current player " + this.state.currentPlayer);

       //check winner
       var winner = this.getWinner();  //get the winner update
       if (winner == 1) {
          Alert.alert("Player 1 has won!");
          this.initializeGame();
       }
       else if (winner == -1){
          Alert.alert("Bot has won!");
          this.initializeGame();
       }
       else if (this.checkTie() == 9){ //check if the match is a draw
          Alert.alert("It's a draw!");
          this.initializeGame();
       }
       //Alert.alert("It's Player "+takePlayer+"'s turn!");
       this.BotMove();
   }
   else {
       Alert.alert("Player 1, please make a move!");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you expected the log statement after the calls to `switchPlayer()` to already include the state changes... Then you must put everything after your call to `switchPlayer` in a callback that has been propagated through `switchPlayer`

```
switchPlayer = (newPlayer, cb) => {
   console.log("Previous player: "+this.state.currentPlayer);
   this.setState(
       {currentPlayer: newPlayer},
       function () { 
          console.log("Current player: "+this.state.currentPlayer);
          // Callers should put their code 
          if (cb) {
              cb();
          }
       }
   );
};

onTilePress = (row, col, ValidMove) => {
       // Switch to other player
       if (PlayerNow == 1) { //if player 1, then change to bot
           this.switchPlayer(-1, () => {
                // Here, you know the state has been updated
            });
       }            
       else if (PlayerNow == -1) {
             ....
       }
       // This code executes before the state is changed, you get the old state
       // All your code should really be in the callbacks to `switchPlayer`
       // or to any method that calls `setState`
       console.log("New current player " + this.state.currentPlayer);
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From React doc:

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

If you want to handle update you could try `componentDidUpdate`

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.currentUser !== prevState.currentUser) {
    console.log('previous user:', prevState.currentUser);
    console.log('current user:', this.state.currentUser);
  }
}
```

If you want to just check that something has been updated (without comparison with the previous value), you can use `render`

```js
render() {
  console.log('current user', this.state.currentUser);
  /* ... */
}
```

There was one more method `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` where you could compare current and the next state but it's marked as **unsafe** now, so you shouldn't use it

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.state.currentUser !== nextState.currentUser) {
    console.log('current user:', this.state.currentUser);
    console.log('next user:', nextState.currentUser);
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate

One tip that can solve many problems: don't use `function(){}` as callbacks, use arrow functions instead `() => {}`, because `function(){}` has its own `this` and arrow functions don't have it

Comment: Not sure why you felt the need to mention arrow functions, it didn't affect this example at all, did it?